# Facebook graph search places

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

While developing module for POI integration from Facebook, I've faced big problem and have no idea how to solve it.

Both and Graph API (v2.1) and FQL (v2.0) have same issues.

Request to find all places within radius of 15km somewhere in Berlin:

```
/search?type=place&center=52.5200066,13.404954&distance=15000&fields=id,name,location,category_list
```

The problems: search granularity is out of control, its not possible to fetch all places by large distance.

- distance 15km, total count = 380, very low granularity, places in distance of 0-6 km
- distance 5km, total count = 361, very low granularity
- distance 2km, total count = 358, very low granularity
- distance 1km, total count = 351, medium granularity
- distance 500m, total count = 354, medium granularity (Eg, Vivolo 0.4 km - not exists)
- distance 400m, total count = 323, high granularity (Eg, Vivolo 0.4 km - exists, ubermetrics Technologies 0.24km - not exists)
- distance 250m, total count - 211, high granularity (Eg, ubermetrics Technologies 0.24km - exists)
- distance 100m, total count - 38, very high granularity

I see only one way: perform N requests with lower distance to have all possible places registered on Facebook.

Could it be somehow possible solve my problem in more elegant way?

Thank you,

Regards,
Nick

Comment: I also encountered this problem. I think they are limiting the resuls on purpose, but I don't know why. Normally, a parameter `q` is expected, with which you search for places containing the query string. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#search

Comment: True, but `q` is used for match on `name` only, and it does not solve the problem of granularity.

Comment: Yes, but I guess FB just didn't create the place search to return **all** results within a certain distance, but only thos narrowed down by `q`. Nevertheless, I think the place search is flawed anyway :-/ I guess you'll have to create an array of points, and run the queries for them one by one with 100m radius. The points/radius circles need to overlap to be sure to get all places. And you'll need to "uniquify" the results.

Comment: As I thought. Appreciated for your comments, Tobi